# Wait for NSURLConnection completion

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

My application must receive few contents of files from the Internet in separated threads (I use NSThread). But thread method completes before content of file is received (because NSURLConnection works asynchronously). And I can't be sure that my file is downloaded when thread is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send a synchronous request:

```
id data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:myRequest returningResponse:&myResponse error:nil];
```

Comment: Is there example of using it? I don't know how to create synchronous request and I don't know how to use NSURLConnection in such way.

Comment: added detail/clarification: call `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]` from your secondary thread.

Comment: oh, I understand. Everything is easier :) Thanks!